# What is the reason for getting libavcodec AVpacket presentation time as 0?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec

Recently I am using FFmpeg library with VS 2017 decode and encode some video data. I used the example codes given with FFmpeg lib packages, `transcoding.c`.

After encoding the video I was trying to extract the frames of the encoded and muxed video.mp4. However, when I read the frames using `av_read_frame (AVFormatContext *s, AVPacket *pkt)`, in the last received frame, `pts` and `dts` times are both 0.

What could be the reason for this? My Video is playing smoothly and I have used `H265` codec.